# How to create a leverage plot for return series?

Tags: r, return, time-series

I found a text with an explanation of the leverage effect and a corresponding leverage plot. Now, I am wondering how I can do the plot in R for my stock return series. I think copy-pasting the text and plot is the most effective way to explain it to those of you who are not familiar with the concept. Any help would be much appreciated!
Best, targa

[image]

[image]

(source: http://stats.lse.ac.uk/fryzlewicz/lec_notes/garch.pdf)

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question or has at least an idea how to approach it?